# Javascript working fine in HTML but not in PHP Heredoc

Tags: php, javascript, html, heredoc

I'm a major noob to php and I might be biting off more than I can chew here.  That being said, I'm facing the following problem:  I've created a form using HTML that dynamically generates additional rows for responses using javascript with the click of a button.  It works fine as a stand-alone html document, however, when I try to use heredoc to put it into a php function, the buttons don't add any rows.  See my code below.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

```
function upsmart_create_profile_form() {
    global $wpdb;
    $data = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM upsmart_profile WHERE wordpress_id=%d",get_current_user_id()),ARRAY_A);

    $media_url = admin_url("media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true");

    $out = <<<EOHTML
    <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<h4>Branding</h4>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#logo_upload").click(function() {
            tb_show("", "{$media_url}");
            window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
                imgurl = jQuery("img",html).attr("src");
                jQuery("#logo_field").val(imgurl);
                tb_remove();
            }
            return false;
        });

        jQuery("#media1_upload").click(function() {
            tb_show("", "{$media_url}");
            window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
                imgurl = jQuery("img",html).attr("src");
                jQuery("#media1_field").val(imgurl);
                tb_remove();
            }
            return false;
        });

        jQuery("#media2_upload").click(function() {
            tb_show("", "{$media_url}");
            window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
                imgurl = jQuery("img",html).attr("src");
                jQuery("#media2_field").val(imgurl);
                tb_remove();
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<table>
    <tr><th>Logo</th><td><input type='text' id="logo_field" value="{$data['logo']}" name='logo'/>
    <input type='button' id='logo_upload' value='Open Media Library'/></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'>Sometext&mdash;moretext.</td></tr>

    <tr><th><br/>Media</th></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'>Now upload the "coolest" piece of media you have. This will be used on the top fold of your generated site to draw users in.
    <br/>
    <input type='text' id="media1_field" value="{$data['media1']}" name='media1'/>
    <input type='button' id='media1_upload' value='Open Media Library'/>
    <tr><td colspan='2'>While you're at it, give us the second coolest piece of media you have as well. Who knows when you might need it?
    <br/>
    <input type='text' id="media2_field" value="{$data['media2']}" name='media2'/>
    <input type='button' id='media2_upload' value='Open Media Library'/>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'><br/>
    <ul><li>The bigger the better&mdash;don't worry, we'll scale these down for you.</li><li>The uploaded files should have solid backgrounds.</li></ul><br/></td></tr>
</table>
<h4>About</h4>
<table>
    <tr><th colspan='2'>Mission Statement</th></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'>Your mission statement should include ...</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'>
EOHTML;
$out .= upsmart_get_editor($data['mission'],'mission');
$out .= <<<EOHTML
    </td></tr>

    <tr><th colspan='2'>"About Us"</th></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'>A good "About Us" writeup should answer the following questions: <ul><li>Who are you?</li><li>What are you doing?</li><li>Why is what you're doing awesome?</li></ul></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'>
EOHTML;
$out .= upsmart_get_editor($data['about'],'about');
$out .= <<<EOHTML
    </td></tr>

    <tr><th colspan='2'>Company History</th></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'>Let us know your background. Some things to think about: ...</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'>
EOHTML;
$out .= upsmart_get_editor($data['history'],'history');
$out .= <<<EOHTML
    </td></tr>
</table>

    </table>

<h3>Company Milestones</h3>
<p>Below, share any milestone achievements of your company.  These could be first-hires, funding that you've received, revenue achievements, or anything else.</p>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {

           var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            element1.name="chkbox[]";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

           var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "text";
            element2.name = "txtbox[]";
            cell3.appendChild(element2);


        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


           }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    </SCRIPT>

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />


    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <TR>
            <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
            <TD>
        <select name="month[]">
            <option value="1">January</option>
            <option value="2">February</option>
            <option value="3">March</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">June</option>
            <option value="7">July</option>
            <option value="8">August</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
        <select name="day[]">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
        <select name="year[]">
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2009">2009</option>
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
            <option value="2007">2007</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="1999">1999</option>
            <option value="1998">1998</option>
            <option value="1997">1997</option>
            <option value="1996">1996</option>
            <option value="1995">1995</option>
            <option value="1994">1994</option>
            <option value="1992">1992</option>
            <option value="1991">1991</option>
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
        </select>
        </TD>
            <TD> <INPUT type="text" name="txt[]"/> </TD>
        </TR>
    <tr><th colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Save'/></th></tr>
    </TABLE>
    </form>
EOHTML;
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: What's your PHP code look like?

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking it, but I don't see a heredoc statement anywhere in the provided code? Nor, do I see any PHP. I did notice that you don't close your `option` tags in your HTML though. That could cause problems, though most browsers will probably fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you.  I fixed the option tags in the html, though it appears that my browser had been picking up the slack for my sloppy syntax and the problem remained.  Regarding the question about the question about the heredoc and what the php code looks like, I'll edit the post to provide some more context.  Thanks!

Comment: What does the final output look like? The browser doesn't care whether the code on the server is PHP or plain HTML; all the browser cares about is the finished generated HTML code it sees. If it works as plain HTML but not from your PHP code then you need to look at the HTML output that the PHP generates, and compare it with what works. Look at the browser console for any JS errors.

Comment: @Spudley Thanks for the suggestion and I think it's getting me somewhere.  The output from the browser console is: "ReferenceError: deleteRow is not defined"  I'm not sure why this would be happening

Comment: @Spudley turned out to be good advice.  I looked at the differences and found that the following line: "if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {" from the php copies over as: "if(null != chkbox &#38;& true == chkbox.checked) {"  Needless to say I have no idea why but I'll keep looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I figured it out with some of Spudley's advice.  I was running into a situation where the html was rendering && in the javascript as &&  This is due to a quirk of wordpress and its use of XHTML as [described here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/unwanted-characters-038?replies=7).  I tried using their suggestions but none of them did it for me.  Finally I just created a separate javascript file and referenced it in the php heredoc.

Answer (score 0):

When using HEREDOC, make sure your HEREDOC line ending has NO spaces in front of it.

Example:

```
<?php
$myStr = <<< ENDL
  Hello, World!
ENDL; // No white space in front of me!
?>
```

Comment: Rob: thanks for the idea, I've checked that (as was advised by another stack overflow post) and found there's no problem there.